# Generic OAuth Provider in Azure Bot channels registration

Tags: azure, botframework

Trying to add a new OAuth setting in Azure bot channel registration using generic OAuth provider.

It is asking fields such as query string template and body template.

Need documentation or a sample filled form so that entries can be made accordingly.

Thx

Comment: You will only need to fill out fields that are appropriate for your provider.  It would be impossible to have documentation for this because every custom OAuth provider will not be exactly the same.

Comment: Can’t the documentation/sample be provided considering standard OAuth2 provider. Need to use the generic one because my provider is not listed in the pre defined ones.

Comment: What oauth provider are you trying to use?

Comment: We have our own OAuth2 service that is based on Owin + Katana.

Comment: Are you using 'generic OAuth2' or 'OAuth2 Generic Provider'  I'm not sure why but we have both of these options in the provider list.  If you are using one, see if the other one makes more sense.

Comment: Yes - ‘generic OAuth2’ makes complete sense. I saw ‘OAuth2 generic provider ‘ first and didn’t think there would be another generic provider.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why it's like that.  I totally understand your confusion and apologies for the got the lack of clarity on that.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the issue. Back to bot building again.